# on etcd node, where can I find standby mode indicator?

Tags: etcd

In 0.4 branch, how can I determine, that node is in standby mode?

I can tell if it is follower/leader by using `/v2/stats/self` API call, but no standby info in there.

https://coreos.com/blog/etcd-0.4.0/

Answer (score 0):

Cluster config API can be used, namely '/v2/admin/config' call. Make sure you are calling it to "peer" (cluster) port, not "etcd" (client) port.

https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/release-0.4/Documentation/api.md